# Facebook User Profile API Not Working for Few Users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is in regards with the Facebook User Profile API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile/). Previously I was able to access details of all the users who messaged our FB Messenger Bot using their USER_ID. But since a couple of days, I'm not able to access details of all the users. I'm only able to access details of few of them.
Example: This User (3200103453356504) regularly texts me, so accordingly to the documentation and how it used to work previously, I should be able to access his information but when I try to access it. It shows the following error:

```
 {
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '320010123356504' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "AFARcLffkfOE55crL3qvJAL"
    }
}
```

But this behavior does not exist for all the users. For ex, For this User ID - 2238372056224053 - its working perfectly fine and returning the correct response with first_name, last_name etc.,
Can you please point out what exactly is the issue.

Thank you,
Murtuza

Comment: That very documentation page you linked to, lists a number of cases in which you might not be able to get this data already …